# User control's instantiation and InitializeComponent code disappearing

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

I have a `User Control` on my `WinForm` application that will be added to my form on its `InitializeComponent()`. After it has loaded, the only thing I do is that I make my main form subscribe to one of this `UserControl`'s events. I do this on my main form's constructor:

```
userControlSettingsFtp.DataChanged += (sender, args) => { RefreshFtpData(); };
```

Everything looks and works just fine. My `User Control` is added and functions well. Until a few builds later that suddenly `Visual Studio` warns me about this user control not having been initialized. And even then when I ignore this problem things look fine. But if I persist on ignoring this problem, the entire definition of this user control disappears from my designer code (as VS had warned me).

Knowing I have other User Controls on my program that work fine, I am still yet to know what really happens under the surface that make my User Control's definitions disappear. I don't even know when this problem triggers since it has no specific reason (that I know of).

Comment: Very vague, as usual.  Use the DesignMode property to prevent dangerous code from running at design time.